# Implicit property access

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do implicit property access with JavaScript. So, I'm trying to do something like:

```js
const array = [];
if (array) { // --> here can it implicitly call .length?
  // code
}
```

I was thinking I'd need to see the internals of `if` statement, but not sure if that's even possible.

Comment: No, and this is a really bad idea in general anyway. Code should be as explicit as possible.

Comment: `the internals of if statement` - the what? here's everything you need to know about [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) - or more in depth [if in the ecma-262 spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-if-statement)

Comment: I meant to modify the internals, but I guess seems like a bad idea and not possible either. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement coerces its argument to a boolean, just like the `Boolean()` function does.

As all objects are truthy, and arrays are objects, no intermediate primitive coercion needed (whose behavior could be overridden), so what you want is simply not possible.

You'll have to type out `array.length`.